# Avoid merge commits in gerrit/git

Tags: git, gerrit

Here is the scenario.

1. Developer A pushes commit c1 to gerrit which is based on commit c
2. Developer B pushes commit c2 to gerrit which is also based on commit c
3. Reviewer merges commits c1 and c2 in gerrit.
4. When reviewer pulls from repo (using git pull --rebase), he/she sees 3 commits.

(Last shown on top, as shown in git log)

Merge "log_message_of_commit_c2" into master (This does not have change ID)

log_message_of_commit_c2

log_message_of_commit_c1

Was merge commit created by gerrit itself when c2 was merged after c1?
Is there any way to avoid this? (Other than developer B rebasing and resubmitting c2, but this involves synchronization between A and B, which is not always possible)

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merge-commit is created by Gerrit.

You can avoid this merge commits by using cherry-pick strategy in Gerrit. See: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#submit_type

Comment: Thanks! Will "Rebase If Necessary" also work in this case? so that C2 will be rebase'd onto C1.

Comment: @SameerNaik: Yes, the Rebase If necessary submit type will also avoid merge commits.